# One big query to perform multiple WHERE statements

Tags: sql, where-clause

I have a list of 116 different combinations of Agents to Vertex/Geo that I have to make sure are paired together.  For example here is small piece of my 116 list.

```
AGNT    Vertex/Geo
5040    440292570
2010    440390000
1010    440390060
1180    440390246
1800    440390570
1130    440391110
1830    440391680
1410    440395020
1060    440397460
2000    440399685
1460    440399687
2020    440710000
1030    440710210
```

I have been using this query to check each pair 1-by-1.  In other words, I have to keep changing the agnt_hse and VRTX_GEOCODE_HSE to check each pair is correct.

```
USE ExternalUser

SELECT  distinct HSE_KEY_HSE AS HOUSE_KEY, AGNT_HSE AS AGENT, VRTX_GEOCODE_HSE as GEOCODE

FROM        ExternalUser.Vantage.HSE_BASE 
      INNER JOIN externaluser.Vantage.HSL_LOB ON HSE_KEY_HSE = HSE_KEY_HSL 
      LEFT JOIN externaluser.Vantage.HSM_MEMO ON HSE_KEY_HSE = HSE_KEY_HSM

WHERE MEMO_NO_HSM = 1 
And sys_hsl = '8777' 
And sys_hsm = '8777'
And delivery_segment_id_hsl = 'C' 
And agnt_hse in ('5040') and VRTX_GEOCODE_HSE != '440292570'
```

Is there a way to run multiple queries all at once?

I am familiar with the UNION command but felt there could be a way to condense the coding even more since I'd be pasting a large query over 100x's if I were forced to use the UNION command.

I'm thinking something along the lines of

```
WHERE MEMO_NO_HSM = 1 
And sys_hsl = '8777' 
And sys_hsm = '8777'
And delivery_segment_id_hsl = 'C' 
And agnt_hse in ('5040') and VRTX_GEOCODE_HSE != '440292570' 
Then agnt_hse in ('2010') and VRTX_GEOCODE_HSE != '440390000' 
Then agnt_hse in ('1010') and VRTX_GEOCODE_HSE != '440390060' 
...etc
```

Maybe I'm going about this all wrong and theres a different way to run the query?
Any information is greatly appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to get exceptions to the list that you are providing.  That is, all rows that match the agent but have a different vertex.

I would phrase this query using an explicit secondary table for the list (if possible) or construct one using a CTE.  Here is the CTE version:

```
with pairs as (
      select '5040' as agent, '440292570' as vertex union all
      select '2010', '440390000'
      . . .
     )
SELECT distinct HSE_KEY_HSE AS HOUSE_KEY, AGNT_HSE AS AGENT, VRTX_GEOCODE_HSE as GEOCODE
FROM  ExternalUser.Vantage.HSE_BASE INNER JOIN
      externaluser.Vantage.HSL_LOB
      ON HSE_KEY_HSE = HSE_KEY_HSL LEFT JOIN 
      externaluser.Vantage.HSM_MEMO
      ON HSE_KEY_HSE = HSE_KEY_HSM join
      pairs p
      on p.agent = agnt_hse
WHERE MEMO_NO_HSM = 1 And
      sys_hsl = '8777' And
      sys_hsm = '8777' And
      delivery_segment_id_hsl = 'C' and
      (p.Vertex <> VRTX_GEOCODE_HSE)
```

Comment: Thank you @Gordon for your reply.  Yes, I am trying to find situations when the Agent doesn't match its Vertex.  I tried to add more pairs to the code like this

`with pairs as (
      select '5040' as agent, '440292570' as vertex union all
      select '2010', '440390000'
   select '1010', '440390060'
   )
SELECT distinct HSE_KEY_HSE AS HOUSE_KEY, AGNT_HSE AS AGENT, `

Comment: @LLL . . . You need a `union all` before each `select` (except the first).

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify your rbdms so I will give a generic example.  The principle should work on most database engines, but you might have to change the syntax.  I am also assuming that agnt_hse and vertx_geocode_hse are integers.  If that assumption is wrong, the required change should be obvious.

```
select yourfields
from yourtables
where concat(to_char(agnt_hse), to_char(vertx_geocode_hse)) in
(select concat(to_char(agnt_hse), to_char(vertx_geocode_hse))
from TheTablesYouAreLookingAt
minus 
select concat(to_char(agnt_hse), to_char(vertx_geocode_hse))
from TheTablesWithTheCorrectData)
```